# Rails: Undefined method error when adding fields to a "form_for ... as: :user"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

In my project, I'm using ideas from *Ryan Bigg's "Multitenancy with Rails"*. Each account has many users, and the account's owner can invite users who can click on the `"Accept invitation"` in an email that is sent to them. If the user is not already logged in/registered on the site, the following form partial will be rendered:

**_anonymous_accept.html.erb**:

```
<%= form_for(@invitation, url: accepted_invitation_path(params[:slug], @invitation), as: :user) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, value: @invitation.email, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.submit "Accept invitation", class: "button" %>

<% end %>
```

On submit, this is handled by the accepted action in the invitations controller:

**invitations_controller.rb**:

```
def accept
  store_location_for(:user, request.fullpath)
  @invitation = Invitation.find_by!(token: params[:id])
end

def accepted
  @invitation = Invitation.find_by!(token: params[:id])

  if user_signed_in?
    user = current_user
  else
    user_params = params[:user].permit(
      :email,
      :password,
      :password_confirmation
    )

    user = User.create!(user_params)
    sign_in(user)
  end

  current_account.users << user

  flash[:success] = "Welcome! You have joined the #{current_account.name} account!"
  redirect_to dashboard_path(params[:slug])
end
```

Now, this works perfectly until I add more fields to the form. I don't want users to be able to register without entering their full name, so I try to add the following lines to the above code samples:

```
# added to the above sample from _anonymous_accept.html.erb

<%= f.label :firstname %>
<%= f.text_field :firstname, class: 'form-control' %>

<%= f.label :lastname %>
<%= f.text_field :lastname, class: 'form-control' %>
```

and this:

```
# added to the permitted user params in the accepted action in invitations_controller.rb

:firstname,
:lastname,
```

These changes breaks the code and serves me this error:

```
NoMethodError in Accounts::InvitationsController#accept 
undefined method `firstname' for #<Invitation:0x0000000478cb58>
```

I am not able to see the logic behind this error, since the email and password params were accepted and not firstname and lastname, when they are all from the same User model.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

EDIT:

From the server log, as requested:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `firstname' for #<Invitation:0x00000005a32208>):
  app/views/accounts/invitations/_anonymous_accept.html.erb:12:in `block in _app_views_accounts_invitations__anonymous_accept_html_erb___2610584697742424634_41597720'
  app/views/accounts/invitations/_anonymous_accept.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_accounts_invitations__anonymous_accept_html_erb___2610584697742424634_41597720'
  app/views/accounts/invitations/accept.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_accounts_invitations_accept_html_erb__4463442190025129055_39118520'
```

EDIT 2:

```
# from db/schema.rb

create_table "invitations", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "email"
  t.integer  "account_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.string   "token"
end

# from models/invitation.rb

class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  before_create :generate_token

  validates :email, presence: true

  def to_param
    token
  end

  private

  def generate_token
    self.token = SecureRandom.hex(16)
  end
end
```

Comment: do u have `firstname, lastname` columns in the table ?

Comment: Yes, they're all in the users table. I have a working edit profile functionality, so the users are able to add their name after registration, but I want to force them to supply their full name when accepting invitation and registering.

Comment: does it work without first and last names ?

Comment: Yes, as i wrote in my question, it works perfectly before i add firstname and lastname.

Comment: what i see, it should work. can u make sure its `first_name` maybe ? also can u post your `server log` when it gives error.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it's `firstname` and not `first_name`. I have a working new account+user (nested form), and edit profile functionality. This is just a problem with this "Accept invitation and register new user" stuff in my invitations controller and views. I don't understand why there was no error when there was just email and password in the form, and why firstname and lastname is stopped, when they're all from the same resource (User). I will update question with lines from server log.

Comment: please provide excertp from db/schema.rb for invitations table, and Invitation model.

Answer (score 0):

Your form is for `@invitation` instance object which have not any `firstname` or `lastname` attributes.
If Invitation has a relation with User model then use `fields_for` with invitation or add  `firstname` & `lastname` fields to your invitation model.

Comment: Thanks! But that doesn't explain why `password` and `password_confirmation` work though, as they're not attributes of `@invitation` either. I just figured the `as: :user` would take care of this. But I could try to nest them with `fields_for`

Comment: Can you post users table schema ?

Comment: Could this be related to Devise? I mean, `email` and `encrypted_password` (with methods for `password` and `password_confirmation`, I guess) are default attributes from Devise, and `firstname` and `lastname` are custom attributes.

Comment: remove `as: :user` and try with `fields_for`

Comment: There's no direct relationship between the User and Invitation model. To use `fields_for` in this case, I would have to change the relationships, wouldn't I? The `Invitation` model belongs to `Account`, and the `Account` model has a many-to-many relationship with `User` through `Membership` (this is a multitenant app).

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the issue comes from devise. Try this way, and let me know...

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << [:firstname, :lastname]
  end
end
```

Add this one to your `invitation.rb` file.

**Updated:**

```
attr_accessor :firstname, :lastname
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't solve it, unfortunately. The same error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Allright, I made it work. This may be a cheap workaround, though.

I replaced these lines:

```
# from _anonymous_accept.html.erb

<%= f.label :firstname %>
<%= f.text_field :firstname, class: 'form-control' %>

<%= f.label :lastname %>
<%= f.text_field :lastname, class: 'form-control' %>
```

... with these lines:

```
<%= label_tag("user[firstname]", "Your first name:") %>
<%= text_field_tag("user[firstname]") %>

<%= label_tag("user[lastname]", "Your last name:") %>
<%= text_field_tag("user[lastname]") %>
```

So I guess I'm just bypassing the call to the undefined methods :firstname and :lastname in the form helper.

Please let me know if this is really bad :-)